# How do you monitor basic performance characteristics in .NET Core apps?

Tags: windows, performance, .net-core, .net-7.0

.NET Framework applications enjoyed extensive support of in-built perf counters which you could monitor using Performance Monitor on Windows.

Apparently .NET Core does not support it.

How do you monitor say Exceptions per sec or Total Time in GC ?

Comment: Check [Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics) at the docs. Nowadays people ask how to use Prometheus to monitor 100 Linux Containers running  .NET services at once, so the answer no longer is "Use Perfomn" or "Use dotnet counters"

Comment: Right now there are 3 different APIs, described in [Compare Metrics APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/compare-metric-apis). Perf Counters is the oldest and only works on Windows. EventCounters came later and the  modern API is System.Diagnostics.Metrics.